# Why christian's don't like islam?

Tags: religion

When i asking christian if he read Koran, he answers: "Why do i need it for? Musleiums are 'idols'
they are blessing Muhammed, and he is bad guy",- bad guy, because acient people have gorems of girls. May somebody explain me who was Muhammed, in source. What is the key idea of islam?

Comment: Muhammad peace be upon him is a "prophet", a "messenger" of God. The idea of Islam is to worship ONE GOD, and to not associate anyone with him because He is One and Only One and He is very Unique. We muslims ONLY worship Allah (the name of God), we honor the messenger (by saying peace be upon him and respecting him, we DO NOT worship him in any way).

Comment: The Koran is here to prove to the Arabs at the time that Muhammad (pbuh) was actually a prophet. The words in the Quran were so good and poetic that some believed that He was an actual prophet and that he wasn’t lying, because he was illiterate and everyone knew that he was very polite, so he couldn’t make the Koran up. The christian needs the Koran, because it is the last miracle and the last way Allah (or god) talked to us. It would be stupid to know that Koran is from God and not read it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Muhammed (peace be upon him) was the messenger of Allah and was the last prophet in Islam. The reason as to why Muslims hold high praise and send blessing towards him is because of his struggles he went through to help shape Islam and help the religion grow. He created the sunnah which is what Muslims follow and was also revealed by angel Jibraeel or Gabriel, the Quran which are Allah’s words.

Islam isn’t an idea, it’s a religion much like other religions people choose to believe in.

Comment: Allah in Quran the same as God in Bible, am i right?

Comment: Not really because from what I’ve learned in Christianity you have the holy trinity which are essential god divided into 3 and Christians also say Jesus is God in human form. Whereas in Islam we believe Allah is the sole creator.